# Java tracer / logger

Tags: java, jvm

I need to trace compiled Java application with thousands of JAR and .CLASS files, do you know any suitable tool that could be attached to the JVM to trace function calls (without the source code)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. [Jprofiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/features.html) can trace method calls / call trees / allocation trees among other data without source code.

Comment: it might be the right tool, but it doesn't work, can't attach to the running JVM and can't start this custom JRE (it quits)... damn :(

Comment: Did you analyse why Jprofiler doesn't work? It could be configuration issue. I used profiler for quite number of application and workd without any issues. Depends on your JVM session( remote,local,application), you would need to attach. Here is helpful link

Comment: Custom JRE ? You can always attach to the VM by using a generic java agent. Use the 'Generic application server' option to attach to the VM. It also work for java programs that start with a main() method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some builtin trace facility, does this help?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/tracing_logging.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is helpful link to configure Jprofiler

http://resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/indexRedirect.html?http&&&resources.ej-technologies.com/jprofiler/help/doc/generalSettings/vm.html